# The process of serialization of a picture box in c#

Tags: c#, serialization

Most examples on serialization and deserialization were for text strings. A simple example how one picture box with a image is serialized and deserialized is what I really want to get me started. What is trying to be accomplished is to have a picture box's properties saved in a file. An example of this would be what process would be involved in the serialization of the picture box below.

```
private void creatpic(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
     pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal;
     pb.Location = new Point(100, 75);
     pb.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(pb_MouseMove);
     pb.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(pb_MouseDown);
     pb.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(pb_MouseButtonUp);
     pb.Image = test.Properties.Resources.track_45;

     pb.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
     this.Controls.Add(pb);
}
```

Another way to save the properties of a picture box beside serialization would also be a big help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is not possible(almost for every control in WinForms). Define a class that defines the properties that you wish to serialize. Do not serialize graphics or image objects, but rather save the file name as a string.  Instantiate the class and assign values to properties that you wish to save for a given control.  Be sure to mark the class as `<Serializable>`, and use that object to "serialize" form controls.

You may also want to create a custom class for each type of control that you wish to serialize.  It would be a good idea to include a Shared method within the class that returns an instance of the control type.  Providing another shared method that created instances of this data type by passing it a control as a parameter would be good, too.

The answer from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e3ede431-b8fc-43bc-85ee-7aba0c5914b6/serialize-a-picturebox-with-all-its-child-controls-and-deserialize-it?forum=vbgeneral)